# Why does access(2) check for real and not effective UID?

Tags: c, unix, posix

I noticed the hard way that the access(2) system call uses the real and not effective user ID for the access control check. While this is in line with what the access(2) man page says on Linux, it still makes little sense to me...

For example, a setuid root program would run under the effective UID of root and real UID of whoever ran the program..now, the program would be able to open `/etc/shadow` with open(2), but the call `access("/etc/shadow", R_OK);` would fail with `EACCESS`

Can anyone educate my on why access(2) works the way it does?

Comment: Mainly because all other system calls do it with the effective user id, so there's no way to check with the real user id in case you run a seuid program.  This allows you to check quickly access to a file for the real user without having to switch with setuid(2) system call.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest answer is that *access()* works the way [the standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/access.html) says it should:

> The access() function shall check the file named by the pathname pointed to by the path argument for accessibility according to the bit pattern contained in amode, using the real user ID in place of the effective user ID and the real group ID in place of the effective group ID.

The standard also describes a different function *faccessat()* which has an option to use the effective UID:

> AT_EACCESS
>   The checks for accessibility are performed using the effective user and group IDs instead of the real user and group ID as required in a call to access().

There is also a [nonstandard function *eaccess()* or *euidaccess()*](http://linux.die.net/man/3/euidaccess) which you'll find on some systems, which checks using the EUID. The standard talks a bit about this function and why it's not part of the standard.

As for why *access()* was original designed the way it was, consider that typical programs don't actually need *access()* very often. If you want to know if you can open a file, it's probably because you're about to open it. So just try to open it and see if it works. It's rare to need to test whether you *can* do something without actually doing it.

The rationale on the standards page hints at the original purpose for *access()*:

> The superuser has complete access to all files on a system. As a consequence, programs started by the superuser and switched to the effective user ID with lesser privileges cannot use access() to test their file access permissions.

The original purpose of *access()* was for a setuid program to test whether the user could perform an action without considering the program's elevated access. That permits a setuid program to limit the scope of what it does without relinquishing its elevated status.

Comment: For the record, this "original purpose" is almost invariably a race condition: it's possible for the file to change [between the `access(2)` call and the `open(2)` call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TOCTTOU) (or whatever you do to the file).  If we're following symlinks, this becomes significantly easier to exploit.  I would not recommend using `access(2)` without careful consideration of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Per the Linux man page, "This allows set-user-ID programs to easily determine the invoking user’s authority."

I suppose this is actually the crux of the function.  Any program can just attempt the desired type of access and handle failure if it happens.  Most do.  You need to check access separately only if you care whether the answer differs from what you would get from the "try and see" approach.