# access(2) vs stat(2) to check if a file is executable

Tags: python, linux, bash, permissions

I have found that using stat and access to check if a file is executable may yield different results. Can anyone explain to me the difference of the two methods?

using C:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>           /* Definition of AT_* constants */
#include <assert.h>
int main(){
    const int access_ret = access("start.r",X_OK);
    const int eaccess_ret = eaccess("start.r",X_OK);
    const int faccessat_ret=faccessat(AT_FDCWD,"start.r",X_OK,AT_EACCESS);
    printf("%d,\t%d,\t%d",access_ret, eaccess_ret, faccessat_ret);
}
```

using bash:

```
$ stat start.r
  File: 'start.r'
  Size: 2769            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 29h/41d Inode: 58066679    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/      ci)   Gid: (  100/   users)
Access: 2016-03-22 22:29:31.234892605 -0400
Modify: 2010-08-06 03:40:03.000000000 -0400
Change: 2016-02-28 20:39:10.244094828 -0500
 Birth: -
$ [[ -x start.r ]]; echo $?
0
```

using python:

```
$  python3 -c '
> import os
> print(oct(os.stat("start.r").st_mode))
> print(os.access("start.r",os.X_OK,effective_ids=False))
> print(os.access("start.r",os.X_OK,effective_ids=True))
> '
0o100644
True
True
```

Comment: in a test I did with a local file with perms 644, I got `1` from your `[[ ...]]; echo $?` test (as we both would expect). Maybe edit your q with results of `uname ; echo $SHELL` ? Good luck!

Comment: @shellter i have some files that behave unusually. `$ uname ; echo $SHELL
Linux
/bin/bash
`

Answer (score 0):

You would notice a difference if your application were running with setuid or setgid privileges.  The [`access(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/access.2.html) manual page tells that:

> The check is done using the calling process's real UID and GID,
>          rather than the effective IDs as is done when actually attempting an
>          operation (e.g., open(2)) on the file.  Similarly, for the root user,
>          the check uses the set of permitted capabilities rather than the set
>          of effective capabilities; and for non-root users, the check uses an
>          empty set of capabilities.

The [`stat(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) call is not affected, giving only the actual filesystem permissions.

The two examples are equivalent: they both return a "success" code.  The `0` exit status in `$?` is success, while python's `True` also reflect success.

But there is something not clear from the examples: the permissions of the file do not have *execute*:

```
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)
```

Perhaps the file has some ACL applied to it which is producing this result.  If so, you would be able to see this using [getfacl](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getfacl.1.html). OP should ask a new question, providing this information as background.

Further reading:

- [Why does access(2) check for real and not effective UID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28099794/why-does-access2-check-for-real-and-not-effective-uid)
- [Setting differing ACLs on directories and files](https://superuser.com/questions/180545/setting-differing-acls-on-directories-and-files)

Comment: the effective IDs explanation doesn't seem to explain it, please see my edited question

Comment: I had realized that, which accounts for the middle where I said "not clear".  Extended permissions seem the place to investigate.

Comment: looks like there isn't extended permissions.
`
$  getfacl start.r 
# file: start.r
# owner: someuser
# group: users
user::rw-
group::r--
other::r--
`
BTW, the file is on encfs.

Comment: Perhaps something is looking at the content of the file rather than the permissions shown by `stat` to decide if it is executable.  I've seen that done with OS/2 and Windows...